# Alter variable pointed by C pointer in Lua

Tags: c, lua, swig

I'd like to have something like this:

int foo(int a, double *b);

In the C implementation, I'd like to alter the variable b points to,
which is a variable in my Lua code.

I couldn't figure out how to achieve this in my Lua code.

Comment: You can't get Lua to directly call your function with the wanted arguments. Instead you need to create a wrapper function which fetches the arguments from the Lua interpreter, and then calls your `foo` function with the expected arguments. When it returns you need to tell the Lua interpreter the returned value (it need to be *returned*).

Comment: I think this is what swig is for.